# React-native: presence of prop dependent on a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say there's a component:

```
const SomeScreen = ({ children, prop1, prop2 }) => {

  <MyComponent
    onPress={handlePress}
    someProp={12}
    propX={prop2}
  >
  {children}
  </MyComponent>
..
```

I know how to assign a value of propX based on whether prop2 has been passed to the screen. For example:

```
propX={prop2 ? prop2 : defaultValue}
```

or to do it at the top of the screen:

```
const SomeScreen = ({ children, prop1, prop2 = 'defaultValue' }) => {....}
```

but what I'm after is to show/hide the whole prop line ('propX={prop2}') based on whether prop 2 has been passed so if prop2 has not been passed it should be:

```
 const SomeScreen = ({ children, prop1, prop2 }) => {

  <MyComponent
    onPress={handlePress}
    someProp={12}
  >
  {children}
  </MyComponent>
..
```

I know I could do a conditional to create 2 versions MyComponent (with and without the propX line) but I bet there'll be a way to do it inline somehow.

Comment: By default, props are `undefined`, so if you pass `prop2` into `MyComponent` and it hasn't been passed to `SomeScreen`, your component will receive `undefined`, which is the same thing as if the prop wasn't passed at all

Comment: I see. Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is Assign a type to your props.

See here is an example

```js
const home=({prop1, prop2:}: {prop1: string, prop2?: string})
{


}

// now if you see above prop1 must be assigned but
// prop2 is optional So now you can call home as below

<home prop1="test" prop2="test2" />
// Or

// see we did not assign a value to prop2
<home prop1="test" />

// this is the same as 
<home prop1="test" prop2={undefined} />
```